# Route::controller with optional parameters in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm just new to Laravel but I immediately fell in love with it. As a not so super experienced php developer I do find the official documentation, although very expansive, somewhat complicated to use and find everything I need.

My question is about the Routing component. As the documentation states you can assign a route to a controller with the `Route::controller` method. So if I want a Blog controller for all `/blog/` routes I assign it like this:

```
Route::controller('blog', 'BlogController');
```

So then if I'd like to acces all my blog posts I acces the the getIndex method by `www.foo.com/blog` or `www.foo.com/blog/index`

But let's say I'd like to be able to display categories via a getCategory method. My url would look like `www.foo.com/blog/category` and if, for example, I want to get the news category from the DB by slug, I'd like to use: `www.foo.com/blog/category/news` as the URI.

My question now is, how do I pass the slug to the url and access it in the getCategory method? Do I need specify it via `Route::get('blog/category/{slug}', 'BlogController@getCategory')` or is there a way to use `Route::controller('blog', 'BlogController')` and to send and acces parameters from the URL in the getCategory method?

I already tried to find it via google and in the official documentation, but I couldn't find a crystal clear answer to this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add parameters to your getCategory method:

```
public function getCategory($category) {
    die($category);
}
```

If you initialize it to null in the parameter list, it becomes optional. Alternatively, you can always pull parameters from the Input object but they would need to be passed in querystring format:

```
$category = Input::get('category');
```

With that said, I'd caution against using the Controller route. It's handy and mimics traditional MVC frameworks, but I believe it's planned to be deprecated -- and honestly, you miss out on some pretty flexible features.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I looked for! But if you say that it might become deprecated, what do you consider the best option to do? Should I define every single route independently instead of using the Route::controller method?

Comment: Yep, exactly. It sounds tedious, and I suppose it is, but it becomes rathe routine. The Resource controllers are always an option for something a bit more automated but I highly recommend using well-defined routes, complete with names ('as' parameter) so you can change url mappings, controllers, parameters, etc. without really touching any of your html links.

Answer (score 1):

using `Route::controller('blog', 'BlogController');` allows you to define a single route to handle every action in a controller using REST naming conventions.then you have to add methods to your controller, prefixed with the HTTP verb they respond to. That means if you have a method called getIndex() it will be executed when there is a GET request to the url "yoursite.com/blog".
To handle POST requests to the same url add a method prefixed with post(ex: postComment()) and so on for other http verbs PUT, PATCH and DELETE.

I think you want something more customized, so you can use a resource controller:

`Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController');`

This will generate some RESTful routes around the blog resource, run `php artisan routes` in your project folder to see the generated routes, it should be something like this:

```
Verb      Path                       Action     Route Name
GET       /blog                      index      blog.index
GET       /blog/create               create     blog.create
POST      /blog                      store      blog.store
GET       /blog/{blog}               show       blog.show
GET       /blog/{blog}/edit          edit       blog.edit
PUT/PATCH /blog/{blog}               update     blog.update
DELETE    /blog/{blog}               destroy    blog.destroy
```

in the action column are the functions that you should have in the controller.
If you want to define more routes you can simply do it with `Route::get` or `Route::post` in the routes.php file

I hope this will make it more clear for you, enjoy routing with Laravel!!!